# Spray paint has yellow gel like substance coming out

Tags: painting

Does anyone know how to fix this when it happens ?[image: yellow sucky substance]

Comment: Shake, shake, shake.  Or get a new can.

Comment: Did you follow the directions? How old is the can?

Answer (score 3):

to prevent this:

Shake the can until you hear the marble rattling, then continue shaking for as along as you have been shaking,  then shake for another two minutes.

Comment: "shake rattle and roll" works too.